# what is the purpose of return_string = " " in the code below. Additionally what is happening in line 4 when " " is added to str(x)

Tags: python

```
def even_numbers(maximum):
    return_string = " "
    for x in range(2, maximum+1, 2):
        return_string += str(x) + " "
    return return_string.strip()
```

Hi i recently started learning how to code and i dont understand equating empty quotation marks and in some codes adding empty quotation marks to strings like in line 4

Comment: That's just a clumsy way of doing `' '.join(str(x) for x in range(2, maximum+1, 2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not empty, it's a space.

Let's say you add the following words:

"hello" "friend"

Without the spaces it would become "hellofriend".

With the spaces it would be "hello friend".